How to use html tags with react-i18next locales?
What is the best way to use html markup inside json locales?
Is the following example from my project correct or there is a better way to handle html markup inside locales?
My locale - foo.json
{
  "hero": {
    "title": "My hero title",
    "text": "<p>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet</p> <p>and another text <my_link>HERE</my_link></p> <ul><li>just</li><li>plain</li><li>list</li></ul>"
  }
}


react component Foo.js:
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';

function Foo() {
  const { t } = useTranslation(['foo']);
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>{t('hero.title')}</h1>
      <Trans
        ns="foo"
        i18nKey="foo.hero.text"
        components={{
          my_link: <a href="my-site.com" />,
        }}
      >
        {t('foo.hero.text')}
      </Trans>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Foo;

i18next config:
react: {
    transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: [ 'p', 'b', 'span', 'ul', 'ol', 'li'],
},

